# Maximum execution time fatal error when importing WordPress xml file

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, import, fatal-error

I want to upload xml file using WordPress Importer plugin. But I am getting this error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\us\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1127" http://prntscr.com/7xbypv  .

I was changed max_execution_time in php.ini file. But still getting same error.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the max time in php.ini? The time "60 seconds exceeded" at least should've changed in your error, if you successfully updated the max time.

Answer (score 0):

The max execution time can be set in different places in the following order of precedence: `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, and in your PHP file. If you changed your `max_execution_time` to a value greater than `60` seconds and then restarted Apache (it appears you are using WAMP), you should see the new value you set in the error. If you are still seeing `60` seconds, it is possible that you set the value in the incorrect `php.ini` file (you can use `php_info()` to see which `php.ini` you are actually using) or that it is being overridden by either `.htaccess` or a value in the code you are using.

If this is a one time issue (local development or the like) you can add the following line to your `wp-config.php` to set the max execution time to `120` seconds (or other value). Setting this to `0` will disable the timeout entirely (should not be using in production).

```
set_time_limit(120);
```